# If $V$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R^n}$, what is $(V^\perp)^\perp$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is $V \subseteq (V^\perp)^\perp$? My intuition tells me that $(V^\perp)^\perp = V$, but I'm not sure if that is right. In what ways can I think about $V^\perp$ that will more easily help me understand what is going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$V^{\perp}$ is the set of all vectors that are perpendicular to $V$.  For example, consider $\mathbb{R}^3$.  Let $V$ be the xy-plane.  What is $V^{\perp}$?  The answer is all the vectors that point from the origin to any point on the z axis?

Ok, so what is $\left({V^{\perp}}\right)^{\perp}$?  We know that $V^{\perp}$ is any vector that lies along the z axis.  $\left({V^{\perp}}\right)^{\perp}$ is the set of all vectors that are perpendicular to the z-axis.  And this, of course, is the xy-plane.

In general, $\left({V^{\perp}}\right)^{\perp} = V$.

Comment: I was just working out the example of the $xy$ plane in my own answer but you beat me to it!

Comment: Would this count as a formal proof that the two are equal? Or is something more rigorous required?

Comment: Something more rigorous is definitely required.  See Cameron Williams' answer below.

Answer (score 1):

This is correct. Think about an element of $V^{\perp}$ as being perpendicular to everything in $V$ (simultaneously). If $V$ is the line $y=x$ in the plane, then $V^{\perp}$ is going to be the set of vectors that are perpendicular to the line $y=x$. This is nothing more than the vectors lying on the line $y=-x$.

If we think about this case further, what is $(V^{\perp})^{\perp}$? It is the set of vectors that are perpendicular to the line $y=-x$. Well clearly this is the vectors lying on the line $y=x$.

This suggests that $(V^{\perp})^{\perp} = V$ as you (correctly) guessed. You can play the same game in $\Bbb R^3$ (see NicNic8's answer). $\Bbb R^2$ has a lot of structure and there are results that hold in $\Bbb R^2$ which don't generalize to higher dimensions. Thus you should always check $\Bbb R^3$ as well.

To see rigorously that $(V^{\perp})^{\perp} = V$, we need to show containment both ways, i.e. $(V^{\perp})^{\perp}\subseteq V$ and $V\subseteq (V^{\perp})^{\perp}$.

We first show that $V\subseteq (V^{\perp})^{\perp}$. Suppose $y\in V$, then we know that if $x$ is any vector in $V^{\perp}$, then $x\cdot y = 0$. That is to say that $y$ is perpendicular to everything in $V^{\perp}$. Hence $y\in (V^{\perp})^{\perp}$. This in turn says that $V\subseteq (V^{\perp})^{\perp}$.

To prove the other containment, we proceed by contradiction. Suppose that $(V^{\perp})^{\perp}\not\subseteq V$. Then there is some element $y\in (V^{\perp})^{\perp}$ such that $y\not\in V$. Since $y\not\in V$, consider $\tilde{y} = y - \text{proj}_V y$, then $\tilde{y}\neq 0$. Furthermore, $\tilde{y}$ is perpendicular to everything in $V$. Thus $\tilde{y}\in V^{\perp}$. However if $\tilde{y}$ is not zero, this says that $y$ is not perpendicular to *everything* in $V^{\perp}$ (particularly, it is not perpendicular to $\tilde{y}$). This gives us a contradiction and so if $y\in (V^{\perp})^{\perp}$, $y$ must also be in $V$, i.e. $(V^{\perp})^{\perp}\subseteq V$.

Since $(V^{\perp})^{\perp}\subseteq V\subseteq (V^{\perp})^{\perp}$, we conclude that they are the same set, i.e. $(V^{\perp})^{\perp} = V$.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one common proof that $V(V^\perp)^\perp = V$:

- $V \subseteq (V^\perp)^\perp$
- $\dim V + \dim V^\perp = \dim \mathbb R^n$
- $\dim (V^\perp)^\perp = \dim V$
- $(V^\perp)^\perp = V$